# Oracle counterpart to `pg_cancel_backend`

Tags: oracle

Considering the Oracle statement `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ...` as... to some degree comparable to the PostgreSQL statement `SELECT pg_terminate_backend()`:

Do you know of any Oracle analogy (better than `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION`) for the PostgreSQL `SELECT pg_cancel_backend()`?

---

***Reference:*** [9.26. System Administration Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-admin.html) (PostgreSQL Documentation)

**pg_terminate_backend**

> **Terminate a backend.** You can execute this against another backend that has exactly the same role as the user calling the function. In all other cases, you must be a superuser.

**pg_cancel_backend**

> **Cancel a backend's current query**. You can execute this against another backend that has exactly the same role as the user calling the function. In all other cases, you must be a superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206907/48347 working.

However, tracing back the error that...

```
exec DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.SWITCH_CONSUMER_GROUP_FOR_SESS (
        sid, serial, 'CANCEL_SQL');
```

... (proposed in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206907/48347) was yielding at my mileage, I got [here](https://blog.tanelpoder.com/2010/02/17/how-to-cancel-a-query-running-in-another-session/) linked from [here](http://oracle-randolf.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/how-to-cancel-query-running-in-another.html) and with the help of [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/10342215#10342215) I was finally able to get a working commands pipeline for my case.

Answer (score 6):

Versions below 18c:

[DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_resmgr.htm#CFAGGDBD)

[SWITCH_CONSUMER_GROUP_FOR_SESS Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_resmgr.htm#i997652)

```
exec DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.SWITCH_CONSUMER_GROUP_FOR_SESS (sid, serial, 'CANCEL_SQL');
```

> If the group name is 'CANCEL_SQL', the current call will be canceled
>   when other switch criteria are met.

From 18c:

[ALTER SYSTEM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ALTER-SYSTEM.html#GUID-2C638517-D73A-41CA-9D8E-A62D1A0B7ADB)

> cancel_sql_clause
>
> Use this clause to terminate an SQL operation that is consuming
>   excessive resources, including parallel servers. You must provide the
>   session id and the session serial number to identify the SQL statement
>   that you want to cancel. If you do not provide these required
>   arguments, the SQL statement will not run.
>
> session_id is required and stands for the session identifier.
>
> serial_number is required and stands for the serial number of the
>   session.
>
> @instance_id is optional. If this argument is omitted, the instance id
>   of the current session is used.
>
> sql_id is optional. If this argument is omitted, the SQL statement
>   currently running in the specified session is terminated.

Example:

```
ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL 'SID, SERIAL, @INST_ID, SQL_ID';
```

Comment: Aha, insightful. I'm trying `DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.SWITCH_CONSUMER_GROUP_FOR_SESS(...)` and in a situation in which an `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION ...` (as `SYSTEM`) is working, this way to `CANCEL_SQL` is yielding an `ORA-29366` wrapped in three `ORA-06512`. Raising to `SYSTEM` or `SYS AS SYSDBA` did not help. Connecting to `/ AS SYSDBA` from the very host also did not help. Does this ring any bell? I found this article http://oracle-randolf.blogspot.com.es/2011/11/how-to-cancel-query-running-in-another.html, but it'll take me some time digesting it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of Oracle you are using the answer is either:

### Oracle 12c or older

I stand corrected: According to Balazs Papp's answer there is a way to cancel a running query in Oracle via the [DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_resmgr.htm#ARPLS050) package.

---

### Oracle 18c or newer

**Yes**, there is an equivalent of the `pg_cancel_backend()` command **in Oracle 18c**.

It is the command:

```
ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL #sid, serial
```

This is documented in the [Oracle Database Release 18c New Features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/newft/new-features.html#GUID-DE70A3CA-B78A-4978-95C1-42315AC8311B) article as follows:

> **Manual termination of run-away queries**
>
> A SQL query consuming excessive resources, including parallel servers, can be terminated using the ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL statement.
>
> This feature enables the database administrator to terminate a runaway SQL query using a SQL statement. This frees the system resources consumed by the runaway SQL query so that other SQL queries can use them.

...and the feature is also documented in the Administrators Guide in the section [5.10.5 Cancelling a SQL Statement in a Session](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-processes.html#GUID-7D8E5E00-515D-4338-8B86-C2044F6D2957) as follows:

> You can cancel a SQL statement in a session using the ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL statement.
>
> Instead of terminating a session, you can cancel a high-load SQL statement in a session. When you cancel a DML statement, the statement is rolled back.
>
> The following clauses are required in an ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL statement:
>
> - `SID` – Session ID
> - `SERIAL` – Session serial number
>
> The following clauses are optional in an ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL statement:
>
> - `INST_ID` – Instance ID
> - `SQL_ID` – SQL ID of the SQL statement
>
> You can view this information for a session by querying the `GV$SESSION` view.
>
> The following is the syntax for cancelling a SQL statement:
>
> ```
>  ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL 'SID, SERIAL, @INST_ID, SQL_ID';
> ```
>
> The following example cancels a SQL statement having the session identifier of `20`, session serial number of `51142`, and SQL ID of `8vu7s907prbgr`:
>
> ```
>  ALTER SYSTEM CANCEL SQL '20, 51142, 8vu7s907prbgr';
> ```
>
> > **Note:**
> >
> > - If `@INST_ID` is not specified, the instance ID of the current session is used.
> > - If `SQL_ID` is not specified, the currently running SQL statement in the specified session is terminated.